# React Native - Android Calendar wont load?

Tags: android, calendar, native, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

So I just starting looking into React Native and I started off by creating a simple application for IOS & Android to understand the basics. All seems to be going well until I tried adding the Android native calendar into my app. Can someone help/explain where I'm going wrong?

I followed & completed the tutorial I found online: https://github.com/chymtt/ReactNativeCalendarAndroid. However the calendar won't load when I try running the app. This is what I get:

[image]

**I found this error when debugging it in Chrome:**

"Warning: Native component for "CalendarAndroid" does not exist"

**My Code:**

```
'use strict';

// External plugins
var React = require('react-native');
var Calendar = require('react-native-calendar-android');

var {
  AppRegistry
} = React;

var BothDevices = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Calendar
      width={300}
      topbarVisible={true}
      arrowColor="#dafacd"
      firstDayOfWeek="monday"
      showDate="all"
      currentDate={[ "2016/12/01" ]}
      selectionMode="multiple"
      selectionColor="#dadafc"
      selectedDates={[ "2015/11/20", "2015/11/30", 1448745712382 ]}
      onDateChange={(data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }} />
    );
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('BothDevices', () => BothDevices);
```

Comment: This has been resolved, just cleaned the project and started it back up

Answer (score 1):

If by any chance you are using react-native 0.19.0 or above, this is the result of a breaking change in RN@0.19.0 release affecting Android UI components.

Please update the component and refer to the new README https://github.com/chymtt/ReactNativeCalendarAndroid to apply the necessary changes